# opencart payment module install 2006 error

Tags: mysql, opencart

On my OpenCart 1.5.6.1 server, I install a local payment provider plugin. It remains on the white screen during editing. When I look at the log records, I see the following error

2017-01-19 2:00:40 - PHP Notice:  Error: MySQL server has gone away
Error No: 2006
SELECT order_status_id, name FROM order_status WHERE language_id = '3' ORDER BY name in /home/SECRET/public_html/system/database/mysql.php on line 50

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is an MySql error. Go through this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html.